# std::hash no type named "hash_policy" when running ska::flat_hash_map

Tags: c++11, hashmap, rcpp

I'm primarily an R programmer, and I'm using Rcpp to run a hash map implementation by Malte Skarupke called [ska::flat_hash_map](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/master/flat_hash_map.hpp) on Windows 10 through RStudio (Microsoft OpenR). The C++ compiler is g++ run with c11 flags.

With no changes to his .hpp file, I am unable to get it running, as it produces the error

```
Line 276 no type named 'hash_policy' in 'struct std::hash<char>'
```

The offending line in flat_hash_map.hpp is

```
template<typename T>
 struct HashPolicySelector<T, void_t<typename T::hash_policy>>
 {
     typedef typename T::hash_policy type;
 };
```

I've found a few benchmark libraries on github that seem to include the library with no problems, and access it like std::unordered_map, so I don't understand why I am having problems getting it to run.

I've also tried providing different types instead of char, sticking to the ones that std::hash should be able to handle automatically, such as int, and std::string.

My source file is really simple, as I'm literally just trying to get a hash map created, for example, my last run was using this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "flat_hash_map.hpp"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]

void run_test()
{

    ska::flat_hash_map<char,char> test_map;

}
```

I'm hoping someone with more C++ experience than myself could shed some light on the problem, or try running the library themselves if the issue is reproducible.

Thanks for the help! 
This is also my first post on StackOverflow, please let me know if there is something I can do to improve my question.

Comment: `void_t<typename T::hash_policy>` this should trigger substitution failure and fall back to the primary template with `fibonacci` policy. you are probably using old G++ compiler version, < 5.0, is that right ?

Comment: check if it works when you replace [line 266](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/master/flat_hash_map.hpp#L266) with `template <typename...> struct voider { using type = void; }; template <typename... Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;`

Comment: @Piotr: Yes, in the R space the toolchain is fixed. On Windows `g++ 4.9.3` is used which is getting old.

Comment: Thanks for the help Piotr, I believe my g++ is running gcc 4.9.3 if that makes sense. Changing the line you suggested allowed the program to compile and run, so that you very much! If you could write an answer explaining a bit more about why your fix worked, I'd like to mark this solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC < 5.0 would not trigger substitution failure on unused parameters within an alias template. This case was actually underspecified in the standard, eventually solved by [CWG Issue 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558).

As a workaround, you should manually replace [line 266](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/master/flat_hash_map.hpp#L266):

```
template<typename...> using void_t = void;
```

with:

```
template <typename...>
struct voider { using type = void; };

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

This forces the usage of template parameters of the alias template, allowing the compiler to SFINAE-out types that don't declare `hash_policy`.